# Access to object info using the pokeapi JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, object, axios, fetch-api, pokeapi

Hey I'm just trying to do the typical pokedex using the pokeapi API with vanilla javascript I'm just returning each pokemon information into an object and it's working, but I don't know how to access the property of the objects I'm trying to access the array but it returns me undefined I don't know how to print each Pokemon name on the console.

This how I'm fetching the info:

```
let pokemonarray = []
const getPokemonAxios = async () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++) {
    try {
      const res = await axios(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`);
      const pokemon = res.data;
      pokemonarray.push({ ...pokemon }) 

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}

const poke = getPokemonAxios()

console.log(pokemonarray)
```

This what shows on console when I print pokemonarray I don't know how to console.log elements like name or type on this object.
[image: pokeapi result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pokemonarray is an iterable so you can loop through the array using a forEach loop and then access and log the properties that are of interest to you

```
pokemonarray.forEach((pokemon) => {
    console.log(pokemon.name)
    })
```

this will log the name of each pokemon